# SignalR Server / Client call in same page

Tags: c#, signalr

I've inherited some SignalR (with JQuery) code that works as follows:

Single page onDocumentReady calls a server side C# method:

```
liveAuction.server.fetchLot(123);
```

This method performs an operation and then calls a client method 'goToLot':

```
 Clients.Group('auction').goToLot(123, 'details');
```

The single page is also listening for this call:

```
liveAuction.client.goToLot = function (lot, lotDetails) {
   console.log('refreshed', lot, lotDetails)
```

I can trace the request through to the browser but sometimes goToLot gets hit and sometimes not.

```
SignalR: Invoking liveauctionhub.FetchLot
SignalR: Triggering client hub event 'goToLot' on hub 'LiveAuctionHub'.
SignalR: Invoked liveauctionhub.FetchLot
```

But goToLot only triggers occasionally and almost not at all on refresh.

Apologies: The question is, why does the client hub event goToLot not get Invoked?

Comment: Apologies Roman, added.

Comment: Perhaps the SignalR connection is not established yet when `onDocumentReady` gets called. Please verify.

Comment: It must be because I call fetchLot as follows:

 $.connection.hub.start().done(function () { liveAuction.server.fetchLot(123);

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue the hubs were being connected to multiple times. Once in the _Layout page and then in the View itself. Removing the one in the _Layout page sorts this out.